# VivaGraphJS: Is there a way to start the display of the nodes from top,left of the container?

Tags: svg, vivagraphjs

I am trying to implement `vivagraph`. However it always shows the entire graph at the somewhere below right corner. From firebug it looks like the `g tag` is getting a lot of matrix transformation.

The problem is that I have dynamically increasing/decreasing nodes per view of the page, so I cant override it with 1 single `translate`. So is there a way to have it done?

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/issues/131

The issue was caused by missing CSS selector